# Check if two datetimes are between two others

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Today I'm facing with problem, which I can't solve.

I need to check if two datetimes (`2019-04-08 13:30:00` - `2019-04-08 15:30:00` ) are between or overlap two others (`2019-04-08 14:00:00` - `2019-04-08 16:00`).

Imagine that those datetimes are event's date. We can see that there is an event between `14:00` and `16:00` so we cant' have other between.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Rezerwacja WHERE
(('2019-04-08 13:30:00.000' between Start and Stop) OR
('2019-04-08 15:30:00.000' between Start and Stop))
```

How to check if there is an "event" already ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check for overlaps, you only need 2 conditions, the start or interval A with the end of interval B, and vice versa:

```
WHERE
      '2019-04-08 13:30:00.000' < Stop 
  AND Start < '2019-04-08 15:30:00.000'
```